# Як об'єднувати теги?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

На нашому сайті вже існують два подібні теги - terms та terminology. Здається, вони мають цілком однакове значення, тому, можливо, варто було б об'єднати їх в один?

Водночас, якщо товариство вважає, що справді варто, то як це зробити? Я ніде не бачу такої опції. Можливо, для цього потрібно мати якісь особливі права? Чи такої опції взагалі не існує? Що тоді робити з тегами-синонімами?

Comment: Приклад з `terms` та `terminology` не дуже вдалий, бо починають з'являтися питання, що не стосуються конкретних термінів, а стосуються підходів до формування термінів, і з'являється потреба розрізняти питання про підходи від питань про конкретні терміни.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Коли натискаєте на тег, відкривається його сторінка. Там є посилання synonyms. За цим посиланням відкривається сторінка синонімів до цього тега, де можна додавати власні синоніми.

Але! Для такої можливості користувач повинен відповідати певним критеріям: "Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2."

Будь-які синоніми може створювати та затверджувати модератор, навіть якщо він не має достатньої кількості очок.